# Getting invalid response back from Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have following servlet which take certain argument and send response:

```
int shares= sh.viewProtfolio().getShareInfoByCompName(value);
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(shares);
```

And I have following jquery in the front end:

```
$("#company").change(function(){
$.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax?get=getSharesInfo&value='+ company.val(),  
    function(response) {
    console.log(response);
   });
});
```

I did debug on the server side, and I did see that I am writing integer number of shares to the response object. But on the front side I am getting '?' symbol. Not sure why, any help would be appreciated.

I also tried setting character encoding, but this time I got some other random character.

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Take a look at the full response in the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug. The servlet must be sending back something in addition to the number of shares.

Comment: Just checked it the only value on response is '?'

Comment: I don't know java-ee, but it sounds like `response.getWriter().write(shares)` isn't doing what you think it should.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, you should post it as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: It looks like the servlet can't write int into the response stream. Yea, I'll post it as answer. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by converting int to String and then writing it to the response.

```
Integer shares= sh.viewProtfolio().getShareInfoByCompName(value);
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(shares.toString());
```

Doc reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write(int)

IO pritntWriter.Write(int) method trying to encode my int result as char. That what caused this unexpected behaviour.